# SQL Server : selecting rows that contain only certain values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hopefully someone can help with this I am struggling to get my head around it.

I have a table called `tblAgreements` that looks like this:

```
AgreementID | GroupDescription |   Live
------------+------------------+--------
20549       |        h&s       |    1
20549       |    construction  |    1
20549       |        HR        |    1
20549       |      Legal       |    1
```

My aim is to pull all agreement ID's that have **only** H&S and construction group descriptions. If an `agreementID` has h&s, construction as well as any other values (like in my example) - it won't be picked up. Only those that have H&S, construction or both.

My query looks like this

```
select * 
from tblagreements 
where groupdescription in ('construction', 'h&s')
```

This would bring back something similar to my example table, which isn't what I would want as there are also HR/Legal groupdescriptions for that agreementID

Does that make sense? Hopefully someone can help me get my head around this!

Thanks as always

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following query:

```
select AgreementID  
from tblagreements
group by AgreementID 
having count(case when groupdescription in ('construction', 'h&s') then 1 end) >= 0 
       and 
       count(case when groupdescription not in ('construction', 'h&s') then 1 end) = 0
```

to get the ids of the agreements that meet your requirements. Then use this query as a derived table in a join operation to get the rest of the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Find total count and count of `h&s` and `construnction` in `GroupDescription` column. Then select `AgreementID` having both the count as `2`.

**Query**

```
;with cte as (
    select [AgreementID]
    , count(*) as [total]
    , sum(case [GroupDescription] 
          when 'h&s' then 1
          when 'construction' then 1
          else 0 end
    ) as [count]
    from [t]
    group by [AgreementID]
)
select [AgreementID]
from cte
where [total] = 2 and [count] = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from tblagreements t1
where groupdescription in ('construction', 'h&s')
and not exists 
     (select * 
     from tblagreements t2 where 
     t1.AgreementID=t2.AgreementID
     and groupdescription not in ('construction', 'h&s'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Following solution provides Agreements with numbers that have both 'h&s' and 'construction', but no any other

```
;with cte as (
    select *
    from tblAgreements
    where GroupDescription in ('h&s' , 'construction') 
), cnts as (
    select cte.AgreementID, count(*) over (partition by cte.AgreementID) as cnt
    from cte
    inner join tblAgreements as a on a.AgreementID = cte.AgreementID and a.GroupDescription = cte.GroupDescription
)
select *
from cte where AgreementID in (
    select AgreementID from cnts where cnt = 2
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM tblagreements
WHERE GroupDescription='H&S';
```

try this. Pulling only data in Groupdesription column that output 'H&S'

Comment: That's not exactly what the OP wants though.